# php array - search for random key where value is over 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array that's made up of random numbers from 0-100.

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest and simplest method of picking a random key from that array that is greater than zero. Ultimately I'm looping through the array, subtracting a value from random keys each loop

Pseudo code:

```
$num_array = array(100,50,60,40,0,30,0,20);

for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {
    $rnd = RANDOM $num_array KEY WHERE > 0  
    $num_array[$rnd] = $num_array[$rnd] - 10;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

EDIT: Once the loop is over I still want my array to contain 0's (originals, and any new ones after subtraction), and all the key positions need to be intact as before

Comment: Why not filter the zeroes out of the array before picking a random one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** simple apply `array_filter` it will filter `zeros` from array

**2nd :** Apply `array_rand` function

```
<?php

$nums = [70, 100, 40, 30, 0, 45, 10];

$new_nums = array_filter($nums);

$key = array_rand($new_nums , 1);

echo $new_nums [$key];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, once the loop is over I still want my array to contain 0's and all the key positions intact as original, will this do that?

Comment: if you want keep the original array means just change the varibale name . check my updated answer . @user1022585

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first remove the zeroes, and only then pick a random value:

```
$nums = [70, 100, 40, 30, 0, 45, 10];
$temp = array_values(array_filter($nums));
$random = $temp[mt_rand(0, count($temp) - 1)];
```

NB: random value is selected according to user comment on [the PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to build an array which doesn't contain zeroes.

```
pos_nums=array();
 foreach ($nums as $num) {
  if ($num > 0) $pos_nums[] = $num;
}
```

PHP has the `array_rand` function documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

If you call

`$pos_rand_keys = array_rand($pos_nums, 1);`

then `$pos_rand_keys[0]` will be a random value.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to put the array_rand into a loop and break if not 0?

Comment: If you have to "keep trying" to pick a random value, the randomness is reduced.  It's better to preprocess the array so you have a good data set, then make a random choice once.